# convert numpy array to string with given format

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I would like to convert a numpy array into a string representation with a given format. This

```py
from io import BytesIO
import numpy

data = numpy.random.rand(5)

s = BytesIO()
numpy.savetxt(s, data, "%.15e")
out = s.getvalue().decode()

print(out)
```

```
3.208726298090422e-01
6.817590490300521e-01
3.446035342640975e-01
7.871066165361260e-01
4.829308426574872e-01
```

works, but `savetxt` is slow. `tofile` is about twice as fast, but I don't know how to get it to work with `BytesIO`. Perhaps there is another alternative.

Any hints?

Comment: `savetxt` creates a `fmt` string by replicating that `%...` to match the number of columns in `data`.  It then does `fmt % tuple(row)`.   The Python string formatting mechanism works on individual numbers (and by extension tuples of numbers), not on arrays.

Comment: Just curious, instead of using BytesIO, wouldn't .npy files, i.e. np.save in byte encoded format do your job?

Comment: @SayandipDutta I don't want the file, I want the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(5)
out ='\n'.join(map('{:.15e}'.format, data))
print(out)
```

Output example:

```sh
2.599889521964338e-02
8.936410392960248e-01
7.074905121425787e-01
4.318334519811902e-01
8.219700656108224e-01
```